# Can use DJI SDK to replicate "Pitch Lock" feature of DJI Go app?

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

I'm trying to replicate the "Pitch Lock" on / off feature of the DJI Go app. How can I do this?

I'm using XCode 8.2.1, building for iOS 10.1, connecting to an Osmo Mobile with an iPhone 6s attached. The Osmo Mobile has the latest firmware (version 01.30.01.52).

Everything works so far (registerApp, connecting via bluetooth, getting handheld button presses, getting gimbal battery updates, getting gimbal updates).

Setting setGimbalWorkMode to either .freeMode or .yawFollowMode doesn't seem to have any effect. No error is returned in the completion block, but there's no effect on Gimbal operation.

The gimbal behaves as if it is in .freeMode (always moves to the exact direction handheld stick is pointing), but DJIGimbalDelegate only receives .yawFollowMode updates (which is what the pitchLock mode should do).

Setting setGimbalWorkMode to other modes results in an error (as expected with Osmo Mobile device).

Here's how I'm trying to toggle pitchLock on/off.

```
@IBAction func pitchLockPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    pitchLock = !pitchLock
    if let gimbal = fetchGimbal() {
        var workMode : DJIGimbalWorkMode = .freeMode // .freeMode .fpvMode and .unknown return error using Osmo Mobile
        if pitchLock {
            workMode = .yawFollowMode
        }
        gimbal.setGimbalWorkMode(workMode, withCompletion: { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("error workMode: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                self.pitchLock = !(self.pitchLock) // back to previous
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here's the delegate, which only reports .yawFollowMode no matter what I do:

```
func gimbal(_ gimbal: DJIGimbal, didUpdate gimbalState: DJIGimbalState) {

 //   var needUpdate = false

    if lastReportedWorkMode != gimbalState.workMode {
        lastReportedWorkMode = gimbalState.workMode

         switch lastReportedWorkMode {
         case DJIGimbalWorkMode.fpvMode:
            print("FPV\n")
         case DJIGimbalWorkMode.freeMode:
            print("Free\n")
         case DJIGimbalWorkMode.yawFollowMode:
            print("Yaw-follow\n")
         case DJIGimbalWorkMode.unknown:
            print("Unknown\n")
         }
    }
```

Anyone getting setGimbalWorkMode to actually change gimbal modes?